# Twilio SMS to Multiple Countries

Tags: twilio

So I'm using Zapier to send text messages to people added to a MailChimp mailing list. A lot of the subscribers are from other countries so I'm just wondering how the interaction works with Twilio.

Will I need a separate number for each country?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You don't necessarily need another number, Twilio numbers can send internationally (mostly, check the individual settings on the number to be sure, UK landline numbers, for example, can't send internationally).

However, receiving a message from an international number may not be a good experience for your users as they might expect a local number. Good news is that it is easy to build this.

You can create yourself an [SMS messaging service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services). Messaging services are a combination of a number pool along with smart uses of the number pool. You can start your messaging service with one number and add others later. When you add more than one number the messaging service will geomatch between the people you are sending to and the numbers available in the pool, picking the best number for the user.

I'm not entirely sure how this works with Zapier, whether you can set a messaging service ID for your Zap. If that's not possible, you could use Zapier to send a webhook to something like a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) which you could set up to send the message.

Let me know if that helps at all.